# Attempting To Discretize the Potential of a Point Charge

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, computational-physics

So as a personal project I am trying to create an program that discretizes the field of a point charge. I want to use the relaxation method but I am not sure what types of boundary conditions I should use. Should I use dirichlet boundary conditions and set the boundary equal to zero since the potential of a point charge at $\infty$ should be zero, or should I use periodic boundary conditions to effectively have the lattice wrap around itself (I think this what they use for lattice calculations in QCD but I'm not sure)? Wouldn't I run into convergence issues if I used periodic boundary conditions?